# what makes it not working while inserting new elements after tokenizing

Tags: c, linked-list, insert, tokenize

i started to work on C to get the general idea. i created a linked list structure, i can insert new elements without any problem. the idea of the list is it increments count when there is same element is already inserted, i read the words from a file by the way.

```
typedef struct Node
{
   char* word;
   int count;
   struct Node *next;
   struct Node *head;
   struct Node *current;
} Node;
```

then when i try to use this list in the code below it adds the words but doesn't increments the count. it acts the word as a new element (it increments when i hard code something else multiple times like insertFirst("testString"))

```
      char* pch;
      pch = strtok(line," ,.-()\r\n\t");
      while (pch != NULL)
      {
        printf("%s-",pch);
        int i = 0;
        for(; pch[i]; i++){
           pch[i] = tolower(pch[i]);
        }
        insertFirst(r,(char*) pch,1); // inserts but doesn't increment the count;
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-()\r\n\t");
     }
```

the code above reads the file line by line, removes all signs, spaces, new lines etc. i want to put the words in the list "r". i am sure there is not an issue in insertFirst method because it works well without tokenize

```
//INSERT METHOD-WRONG ONE
void insertFirst(Node* r, char* word, int count){
   if(find(r, word)){
       struct Node* temp = find(r,word);
       temp->count += 1; //
   }
   else{
      struct Node *link = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
      strcpy(&link->word, &word);
      link->count = count;
      link->next = r->head;
      r->head = link;
   }
}
```

thanks to comments the code below works like a charm

```
//WORKING INSERT METHOD
void insertFirst(Node* r, char* word, int count){
   if(find(r, word)){
       struct Node* temp = find(r,word);
       temp->count += 1;
   }
   else{
      struct Node *link = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
      link->word = malloc(strlen(word)+1);
      strcpy(link->word, word);
      link->count = count;
      link->next = r->head;
      r->head = link;
   }
}
```

Comment: where is your tokenize code inserted/called? strtok is 1) not reentrant 2) not allocating memory for the tokens, so it's tricky to use.

Comment: 1) `strcpy(&link->word, &word);` --> `strcpy(link->word, word);`

Comment: 2) you haven't allocated memory for `link->word`. you must add `link->word = malloc(strlen(word)+1);` just before `strcpy(link->word, word);`.

Comment: thanks, allocating some memory fixed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is the solution that [vadim_hr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4028638/vadim-hr) solved

```
//WORKING INSERT METHOD
void insertFirst(Node* r, char* word, int count){
   if(find(r, word)){
       struct Node* temp = find(r,word);
       temp->count += 1;
   }
   else{
      struct Node *link = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
      link->word = malloc(strlen(word)+1);
      strcpy(link->word, word);
      link->count = count;
      link->next = r->head;
      r->head = link;
   }
}
```